SocketException: Connection refused when connecting to PostgreSQL from mobile device
My code is running on vscode, and I am using my phone to run the application wirelessly. I am connected to the same wifi network too. When I run the application my laptop, it connects to the postgreSQL db, I can register an account. However when I try to register to my phone it shows this error:
Exception has occurred.
SocketException (SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = 192.168.1.96, port = 37866)
This is my code block
import 'package:postgres/postgres.dart';

Future<void> registerUser(
  String username, String password, String email) async {
  final connection = PostgreSQLConnection(
    '192.168.1.96', // Host
    5432, // Port
    'thesis', // Database name
    username: 'postgres', // Username
    password: '123', // Password
  );

  await connection.open();

  await connection.execute(
    'INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) VALUES (@username, @password, @email)',
    substitutionValues: {
      'username': username,
      'password': password,
      'email': email,
    },
  );

  await connection.close();
}



Network Connectivity: Verified that both the laptop and mobile device are connected to the same Wi-Fi network. No issues with network connectivity were detected.
Port Availability: Checked if the port used by PostgreSQL is available for incoming connections. No conflicts or issues were found regarding port availability.
Firewall Settings: I've checked my laptop's firewall settings to ensure they are not blocking incoming connections on the PostgreSQL port (typically 5432). No relevant blocks were found.


That is a weird error message.  Why is it connecting to port 37866? Or if that is the client port, in which case why is it reported immediately adjacent to the server IP address?

I think the port that was displaying in the error was the port in my phone, because when I try to rerun the code the port in the error keeps on changing.

The default PostgreSQL port is TCP 5432. Also check if the Postgres server is running on all interfaces, not only localhost/127.0.0.1/::1

@Robert I checked my postgresql.conf file and it listens to all available network interfaces.
This is the setting of my list_addresses in the postgresql.conf file: listen_addresses = '*'

I fixed the problem using this solution.
The solution involves using the adb reverse command to forward traffic from a host port to a device port.
In my case, I executed the following command:
adb reverse tcp:65535 tcp:39577

I got the device port from when I run the command adb devices in cmd and it showed the connected ip with the port: 192.168.1.216:39577
